# How to properly import an SCSS that imports other CSS / SCSS

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an SCSS in an angular project that's importing another SCSS from node_modules:

```
@import "node_modules/grapesjs/src/styles/scss/main.scss";
```

That SCSS imports other styles:

```
@import "node_modules/spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum";
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import "node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror";
@import "node_modules/codemirror/theme/hopscotch";


@import "gjs_variables.scss";
```

But that causes this error:

[image: Cant find stylesheet to import.]

I am guessing this means I need to specify the path properly.  I have this in my angular.json:

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/styles",
            "."    // **this is where the node_modules directory is**
          ]
        },
```

My guess is that the path in main.scss is relative to that file. I can't figure out how to specify that.

Comment: I tried that too. Same error. 
The reason I am trying to import SCSS is because otherwise I can't change the theme of the third-party component.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's put in the `styles` property of your `angular.json` file.

Also, it doesn't matter the extension, the compiler will convert it to JS anyway (unless it's an asset, then it stays as it is)

The path is

```
./node_modules/...
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, that didn't work either.  Been trying different combinations :-).

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve], because every project I have ever made used that syntax ...

Answer (score 0):

To import the style from node_modules use ~ prefix like this

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import "~toastr/toastr";
@import "~react-select/dist/react-select.css";
@import "~react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css";
```